# Detect or intercept moment when a batch is closed via mouse (X console button)

Tags: batch-file

I need to run a batch "Script A" and this is only run either when the batch is closed programatically via the "Do you want to exit [y / n] questions" or when all the scripts within the batch are concluded.

If anytime the user decides to close the batch via the mouse button ("X" on the upper right-hand side of the console) of if the batch crashes, "Script A" will, unfortunatelly, not be executed.

How can I programatically intercept any moment of "X" and launch another batch to finalize the deed?

Kind regards,

Maleck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following simple scheme seems to work. The cleanup script calls the main script via the START command with the /WAIT option. This ensures control will return even if the child process is killed by closing the window.

The parent cleanup script will normally prompt if you want to *"Terminate batch job (Y/N)?"* if the main script is killed by closing the window. I pipe N into the START command to automatically answer that prompt, should it arise. The outer block redirection of stderr to nul suppresses the ugly `^C` (Control-C) that shows up when the main window is killed.

The main batch file isn't STARTed directly, but instead is launched via the CMD /C command. This ensures control will return even if the main script is killed by pressing Control-C. This also eliminates the need to put an EXIT command in the main script (which might never be executed any way).

**cleanup.bat**

```
@echo off
:: Launch the main program and don't continue until it completes (or is killed)
2>nul (
  echo N|start /wait "" cmd /c main.bat
)

:: Cleanup up begins here
echo Time to wrap it up!
```

Here is a trivial **main.bat** to test the return functionality

```
@echo off
echo This is the main script.
echo(
echo    Press any key to close normally
echo or Close this window via the console window X button
echo or Press Ctrl-C to break out of this script abnormally
pause >nul
```

***EDIT***

Of course there is nothing to prevent a user from closing the "cleanup.bat" window before the main script terminates, which puts you right back to square one :-(

You can run a VBScript or Jscript via wscript without any visible window to close. The (VB/J)script can then launch the main.bat script and then launch a cleanup.bat script only when the main process finishes (or is killed). That would make it more difficult for an end user to interfere with the process of kicking off the cleanup script.

**master.vbs**

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "D:\test\main.bat", 1, TRUE
WshShell.Run "D:\test\cleanup.bat", 1, TRUE
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

But once you cross that threshould, why not do the entire project in (VB/J)script?

Comment: I've tested the above script and it works ... but only if we delete in the master.vbs the line `WshShell.Run "D:\test\main.bat", 1, TRUE` and change from 1 to 0 the line `WshShell.Run "D:\test\cleanup.bat", 0, TRUE`. Now, the master will call the cleanup.bat. This bat will run invisibly and call the main.bat right away. When the main is finished or killed, as you said, the cleanup.bat (invisible) will do the last pre-defined job and quit. Your script helped me to delete a lock that I have implemented sometime ago in another batch which envolves intranet users accesing one file.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A batch cannot tell when it gets closed from the red X. Therefore, any code handling the close from the X will have to come from somewhere else. One possibility would be to make another batch use `TASKLIST` to monitor when the first batch gets closed.