# Batch - Reboot computer if a batch file ends

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, terminal

Essentially we have 2 batch files, one which is the "wrapper" if you will, calling another batch file so it starts as `/min` (minimized). This batch file then ends once it has launched the 2nd batch file.

This contains a loop, which keeps spawning an RDP session after it is closed.

The problem is, if the user ALT-TABs and closes the batch, they are just left with an empty desktop (as we task kill explorer). Is there a way of force rebooting the machine if that batch loop ends?

Thanks!

Comment: i would use vbs script instead of batch file since you can use vbs to tap into running processes and launch applications in background if a particular process is not in the list.

Comment: Kind of sounds like you're asking something along the lines of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657622/detect-or-intercept-moment-when-a-batch-is-closed-via-mouse-x-console-button. Seems the verdict is that you can't accomplish this without a VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard cmd command:

```
shutdown /r
```

```
Usage: shutdown [/i | /l | /s | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e | /o] [/hybrid] [/f]
    [/m \\computer][/t xxx][/d [p|u:]xx:yy [/c "comment"]]

    No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
    /?         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
    /i         Display the graphical user interface (GUI).
               This must be the first option.
    /l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
    /s         Shutdown the computer.
    /r         Full shutdown and restart the computer.
    /g         Full shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is
               rebooted, restart any registered applications.
    /a         Abort a system shutdown.
               This can only be used during the time-out period.
    /p         Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning.
               Can be used with /d and /f options.
    /h         Hibernate the local computer.
               Can be used with the /f option.
    /hybrid    Performs a shutdown of the computer and prepares it for fast startup.
               Must be used with /s option.
    /e         Document the reason for an unexpected shutdown of a computer.
    /o         Go to the advanced boot options menu and restart the computer.
               Must be used with /r option.
    /m \\computer Specify the target computer.
    /t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
               The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
               If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
               implied.
    /c "comment" Comment on the reason for the restart or shutdown.
               Maximum of 512 characters allowed.
    /f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
               The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is
               specified for the /t parameter.
    /d [p|u:]xx:yy  Provide the reason for the restart or shutdown.
               p indicates that the restart or shutdown is planned.
               u indicates that the reason is user defined.
               If neither p nor u is specified the restart or shutdown is
               unplanned.
               xx is the major reason number (positive integer less than 256).
               yy is the minor reason number (positive integer less than 65536).
```

Comment: Thanks, but you are completely missing the point, I want the machine only to shutdown when the batch file is closed (because it shouldn't be closed..)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

Do you really need batch to be visible (minimized) or can it be hidden?

If it can be hidden, just use VBScript to launch it hidden:

```
With CreateObject("W"&"Script.Shell")
    .Run "LongRun.bat", 0
End With
```

If you really need batch to be shown, you could make a hidden script which will wait for batch to terminate and reboot.

Step 1: Launch script hidden (`Start.vbs`):

```
Set WsShell = CreateObject("W"&"Script.Shell")
WsShell.Run "Hidden.vbs", 0
```

Step 2: `Hidden.vbs` will launch batch and wait it to return:

```
'This script is supposed to start hidden!
Set WsShell = CreateObject("W"&"Script.Shell")
WsShell.Run "LongRun.bat", 7, True
'WsShell.Run "REBOOT.EXE ..." 'Must remove comment and complete command line
MsgBox "Rebooting..."
```

Now `LongRun.bat` is running, `Hidden.vbs` also (but not visible).

If somehow `LongRun.bat` is terminated, `Hidden.vbs` will continue its execution and reboot.

([WScript.Shell.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) documentation)

EDIT: Notice `"W"&"Script.Shell"` is same as `"WScript.Shell"` but StackOverflow doesn't allow me to write it!